# How to Condense SQL Rows Using Stuff?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data that looks like:

#test

| RecordID | Name | hasSpanishVersion | Type | TypeID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test One | Yes | FormType1 | 1 |
| 1 | Test One | Yes | FormType2 | 2 |
| 3 | Test Three | No | null | null |
| 4 | Test Four | Yes | FormType3 | 3 |
| 5 | Test Five | Yes | FormType3 | 3 |

I also have another table that looks like:

#formTypes

| TypeID | FormType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FormType1 |
| 2 | FormType2 |
| 3 | FormType3 |

What I am trying to do is condense the Type column where there are like-RecordIDs / Names. If "hasSpanishVersion" is null, the following two columns will also be null.

I am wanting the example table to look like:

| RecordID | Name | hasSpanishVersion | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test One | Yes | FormType1, FormType2 |
| 3 | Test Three | null | null |
| 4 | Test Four | Yes | FormType3 |
| 5 | Test Five | Yes | FormType3 |

I have tried the following code, but this only takes all of the FormTypes and condenses them for each of the three different types:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + t.formTypeSpanish 
          FROM #test t
          WHERE t.TypeID = ft.TypeID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FormTypes
FROM #formTypes ft
GROUP BY ft.TypeID, ft.FormType
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Do you even need your second table? You don't appear to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might let your grouping column put in `Where` in a correlated subquery that and you concatenate value in `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
   RecordID, Name,hasSpanishVersion,
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + tt.[Type] 
          FROM formTypes tt
          WHERE 
          tt.RecordID = t1.RecordID AND 
          tt.Name = t1.Name AND
          tt.hasSpanishVersion = t1.hasSpanishVersion
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as FormTypes
FROM formTypes t1
GROUP BY RecordID, Name,hasSpanishVersion
ORDER BY 1
```

if your sql-server support [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) there is another simple way to do that.

```
SELECT RecordID, Name,hasSpanishVersion,STRING_AGG([Type] ,',') 
FROM formTypes
GROUP BY RecordID, Name,hasSpanishVersion
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1bc37528205cc6c80d3af16e4a675c7)